# Eclipse - limiting a command's visibility to a specific perspective

Tags: eclipse

How do I limit the visibility of an Eclipse command in menus and the toolbar to just one perspective? It is currently showing up in all perspectives, but it only makes sense to have it around when working in this particular perspective. It seems like this could be done with "contexts", but I was wondering if there was something simpler.

Comment: Is this Eclipse command a command you're contributing to Eclipse through a plug-in, or is this Eclipse command a standard Eclipse command?

Comment: It's a command I'm contributing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732243/removing-a-view-from-eclipse-window-show-views/2732306#2732306 might help